# Get a list of nearest business

Tags: android

I am trying to use MapView and I want to show in the map some points of interest (like restaurants or stores) near my location. Is there a way in the api to get this kind of list? I know I can do this manually, but first I would need to get the geolocations. So which would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Android does not have APIs for this.

Comment: So then would I need to manually get the geo points of the business I want to show? Or is there a way to get them somehow through google search? THose applications like showing the closest starbucks have to do it in someway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checking current location is possible. but we can get the center point of set of lat & lang. get nearest lat&lang from current location is the solution for now.

Comment: I don't understand. What I want is to show what kind of stores, restaurants are close to the current location.

Comment: I think that what I want to get is not possible using a MapView (unless I create my own overlay). But it is possible to call the Maps app via an intent and show the nearest business:
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=business+near+city"));
This is the quickest way. You can change business for whatever you want, as well as city.